# How to explicitly assing font sizes to different memoir elements (e.g., part,chapter,title..etc)

Tags: memoir, fontsize

I am trying to explicitly assign font sizes to elements of the memoir documentclass. 
For example, I want the part to be 17pts. Chapter titles to be 14pts. Section titles 13pt. and normal text 12pt.

I read the memoir document class, in page 104, it shows the heading styles naming, I used it as in my MWE, but I don't know if this is the right way to do it.

And still, I did not know how to set the normal text size.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\partnumfont}{\fontsize{17pt}{\baselineskip}\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\partnamefont}{\fontsize{17pt}{\baselineskip}\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\parttitlefont}{\fontsize{17pt}{\baselineskip}\bfseries}

\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\fontsize{14pt}{\baselineskip}\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\fontsize{14pt}{\baselineskip}\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\fontsize{14pt}{\baselineskip}\bfseries}

\renewcommand{\secheadstyle}{\fontsize{13pt}{\baselineskip}\bfseries}

\renewcommand{\subsecheadstyle}{\fontsize{13pt}{\baselineskip}\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\subsubsecheadstyle}{\fontsize{13pt}{\baselineskip}\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\paraheadstyle}{\fontsize{13pt}{\baselineskip}\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\subparaheadstyle}{\fontsize{13pt}{\baselineskip}\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\part{parts title and text are 17pt}
\chapter{chapters are 14 pt}
\section{section titles are 13 pt} 

Normal text is 12 pt.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Normalsize of 12pt is obtained by passing the `12pt` class option, the default is `10pt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following from the comment by @daleif you use an option to the `memoir` class command to set the general text size (no option, default is 10pt). You need

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
```

to get 12pt as the normal text size.

If you specify this then the default font size for Part and Chapter titles is `\huge` which corresponds to 25pt. For your 17pt size use `\Large` and for your 14pt size use `\large`.  You are on your own for a 13pt font macro as `memoir` provides for 12pt and 14pt font size macros but not 13pt.

Chapter 3 *Text and fonts* of the manual (`< texdoc memoir`) details the font size macros and Chapter 6 *Document Divisions* contains information (if you search diligently) about the size of fonts used in the divisional headings.

Comment: @Sari If my answer solved your problem about the normal font size, please accept it.

Comment: @Sari Can you think of any reason why I should spend time and effort in trying to help you?